# Filter data in Axes object

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a countplot with a clumped-up x-axis. I tried to solve this by rotating the labels and increasing the size of the figure. As a result, my x-axis was no longer clumped but the labels became unread-ably small.

I thought I could solve this by filtering out data that's below a certain threshold. Like, I didn't want to display counts < 50 but I have no clue how to achieve this.

My current code + plot.

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
ax = sns.countplot(x="Model", data=csv_data)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=40, ha="right")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (50, 10)
plt.show()
```

[image: countplot]

Comment: Do you want to show all the labels in the x-axis?

Comment: No, just the data and labels with values higher than given.

Answer (score 0):

To separate the data from the visualization, the 'Model' is aggregated and combined with the original data to create a visualization of the conditional extraction.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random, string

model_name = []
model_list = []
for i in range(100):
    n = np.random.randint(5,15,(1,))
    tmp = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=int(n)))
    model_name.append(tmp)
    model_list = random.choices(model_name, k=100)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Model':model_list})
# new dataframe by value_counts
df2 = df['Model'].value_counts().to_frame(name='count')
df2.reset_index(drop=False,inplace=True)
df2.columns = ['Model','count']
# dataframe combine
df = df.merge(df2, on='Model')
df = df[df['count'] >= 2] # condition

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9),dpi=144)

sns.set_style('whitegrid')
ax = sns.countplot(x="Model", data=df)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=40, ha="right")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]
No condition

[image]